# How to to divide column containing formulas and hard-coded strings into two separate columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column that consists of hard-coded cells as well as formulas. Based on whether a specific cell is either hard-coded or contains a formula, I want to display it in two separate new columns.

So far that's pretty easy, e.g. using Go to - Special. However I need to maintain the row, and that's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2517-excel-if-column-contains-value-text-then-copy-cell.html) guide. And just make the text you're looking for an '=' sign. The '=' will denote a formula.

Then apply the same rule to the rest of column.

You can then do the same and make the text not looking for an '=' sign.